# Optimal distance between clusters in space

Tags: math, graph-algorithm, partitioning

I start working at a project for an CNC machine and I am struggling to make an optimal algorithm to cut different parts of some type of material.

The problem can be put in this way: I have a set of clusters. Each cluster represent the form I wish to cut. I need to find a way to move the cutting edge to visit all clusters but only one time for each cluster. Also the path that I choose needs to be absolutely optimal. I also need to do this for around 5.000 edges. As an input I have a matrix of all the distances from each edge to others. The Dijkstra or Froyd algorithm can not handle so many edges. I tried the single-linkage method with the Slink optimization but it fails in most of the possible cases.

[image]

This is an example of what I want to do. The red lines form the clusters and the blue lines represent the path of the cutting edge. I need to find the shortest path from a random cluster to each other cluster visiting only once the most suitable edge of each cluster. How to do this?

Comment: Where is the limitation stemming from the large number of nodes, running time? The wikipedia has it that  a newer impementation of the Dijkstra  algorithm (Fredman & Tarjan 1984) should be faster like with a factor of 1000 for this problem size.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Do you know the order in which to visit the clusters? If not, this pretty much looks like a Travelling Salesman Problem on the clusters (which would be NP-hard, but can be pretty well approximated, if you can live with an approximate solution).

Comment: No, I do not. That is the problem. The clusters are already made. I need just to find a very fast way to extract the best node from each cluster to make the most shortest path. This needs to be done in under a second. Also I already manage to extract a possible solution using a combination of heuristics in a A* algorithm. But the time is pretty bad around 6 seconds and the solution is not even near the best solution.